# Beautiful Soup Install

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a couple question about installing packages on python. I have looked and tried to find info on easy_install.... where do I get it and how do I make it work. The doc for it is very confusing.

I understand once I have it I can simply use it to easy_install beautifulsoup4. I just can't get this to work.

I tried downloading setup tools, but it does't seem to work.... any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you cannot install setuptools then you need to ask about that, providing all necessary details. Once you have setuptools installed you can install everything else with `easy_install`.

Comment: It depends on your OS.

Comment: The only thing you should install with `easy_install` is `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows binaries of setuptools are available at the link below. Once these are installed you should be able to use the easy_install command.

You need to add the directory of easy_install.exe to your Windows PATH environment variable, if you don't want to type the full path of easy_install each time.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Answer (score 0):

(i'm writing this to answer to the comments of your question)
Try installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on windows,
then it'll be easier to use easy_install, pip and stuff like that!
Might help!